# React-router: nested routes error

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, react-redux

The below is my code for routing

```
  <Router history={ browserHistory }>
    <Route path="/" component={ App } >
    <IndexRoute component={ Indexpage } />
      <Route path="users" component= { Users } >
        <Route path="signin" component={ Signin } />
        <Route path="signout" component={ Signout } />
        <Route path="signup" component={ Signup } />
      </Route>
    </Route>
</Router>
```

The only path that works are path with components {App},{Indexpage},{users}

{users} component is nested within {App} itself. so when I go URL: "/users", it works.

However, when I go to the remain URLs that are nested within {users} such as {signin}, {signout}, {signup}. Error in chrome state: `GET http://localhost:8080/users/bundle.js 404 (Not Found)`

But when I try to change Route to IndexRoute for one of the nested components within user, that particular route will work.

I have place {this.props.children} for both {App} and {Users} component.

Can someone advise how to make the nested users routes work? I'm using webpack to bundle my jsx.

Edit 1: I included my webpack.config below

```
const webpack =  require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";

module.exports = {
  entry: ['./public/src/index.js'],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/src'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel',
      query: {
        presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
      }
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: 'public'
  },
  plugins: debug ? [] : [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: true , compress: { warnings: false }}),
  ]
};
```

Comment: It seems like more to do with webpack config. When you trying to access `/users/*` the app is looking for `bundle.js` inside `/users` instead of `/`.

Comment: Please explain further?

Comment: I explained this why this is and how to fix it.  Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The guy who answer: alexi2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6060774/alexi2)

Thanks and shoutout to the link above.

The key to deep nesting routes using react-router appears to be , if you try to hard land based on URL. It will not work.

Go Let's say if in user component (ES6).. In order to go to route "/users/signin", your component should look like the below:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

export default class Users extends Component {
render(){
  return (
    <div>
      <Link to="/users/signin">Sign in</Link>
    </div>
   )
 }
}
```

Oh and remember to include {this.props.children} in your parent component.

Answer (score 7):

You are getting this error (http://localhost:8080/users/bundle.js 404 (Not Found)) not because there is an issue with React Router's way of nesting routes, but because your bundle.js file is only accessible at your route folder (or first level of routes).  Thus it cannot load your javascript bundle.  Don't worry, web pack provides a very useful fix for this.  Public path: https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/.

So in your webpack.config replace:

```
output: {
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/src'),
  filename: 'bundle.js'
},
```

With:

```
output: {
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/src'),
  publicPath: '/',
  filename: 'bundle.js'
},
```

Now inspect your page - you'll notice that the script tag carrying your bundle.js file looks something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bundle.js?8816b34afd221213c243"></script>
```

Notice the slash before the bundle.js.  Your page now knows to look for the bundle js file at not only the first level of routes, but any others. So whether you do a hot refresh at http://localhost:8080 or http://localhost:8080/users, your browser will be able to load your bundle.js.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a `/` in front of the nested routes, like this:

```
<Router history={ browserHistory }>
  <Route path="/" component={ App } >
    <IndexRoute component={ Indexpage } />
    <Route path="users" component= { Users } >
      <Route path="/signin" component={ Signin } />
      <Route path="/signout" component={ Signout } />
      <Route path="/signup" component={ Signup } />
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Router>
```

Also you could try using:

`<Link to="/users/signin">Signin</Link>`

within your `Users` component to navigate to those nested routes.

You can use this by putting:

`import { Link } from 'react-router'` at the top of the file.

[Docs on react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/RouteConfiguration.md)

Comment: Tried. But didn't work. Apparently, it sounds like webpack problem. But I'm not sure neither.

Comment: How could it be a webpack issue if you can already access components within the bundle?

Comment: That was What I thought, but I saw a couple of issues on webpack-dev-server, where nested routes cannot be found. Moreover the error msg stated `users/bundle.js` not found.

It naturally not found because I don't have such file or folder.

Comment: [Github issues boilerplate](https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate/issues/113)

I have no idea what they were trying to say except their conversation bear some similarities to my problem.

Comment: In your UI are you navigating to `/users/signin` through a `<Link>` within `/users`? Or are you hard loading the URL in the browser?

Comment: hard landing url. Previously I never tried doing deep nesting with webpack, so whenever I wanted to try to see if files is loaded and route works, I just change URL manually.

Comment: Try using `<Link>` as suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

bagofcole's answer is good, but the problem I was having with nested routes was that an api route that was called was returning the static html file instead of its expected response.

Turns out for that api call, the path I specified was missing a '/' at the beginning.

```
  return axios.get('api/isAuthenticated')  // INCORRECT
  return axios.get('/api/isAuthenticated') // CORRECT
```

The nested route path upon refresh was un-styled. This was due, similarly, to an incorrect CSS path in the html file:

```
   <link rel='stylesheet' href='./stylesheets/style.css' /> // INCORRECT

   <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' /> // CORRECT
```

So much trouble using React-Router. If I get any more puzzling bugs like this, I may stop using it, or at least use the static routes library the same team offers.